# CIDR block 10.0.96.32/18 overlaps with pre-existing CIDR block 10.0.96.0/28 from subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, cidr

Wondering how does this overlap, it seems like it comes afterward.

```
CIDR block 10.0.96.32/18 overlaps with pre-existing CIDR block 10.0.96.0/28 from subnet-3fa92058.
```

[image]

Comment: confused, what is CIDR of your VPC and subnet 3fa92058?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert each quad to binary...

```
$ dc -e '2o 10p 0p 96p 32p' | xargs printf '%08d\n'
00001010
00000000
01100000
00100000
```

Now you've got the IP address as a binary number:

```
00001010000000000110000000100000
|       |       |       |
```

The first 18 bits of that represent the network for this IP address...

```
00001010000000000100000000000000
******************--------------
```

Which, if you convert back to dotted quad notation, look like this:

```
$ dc -e '2i 00001010 p 00000000 p 01000000 p 00000000 p'
10
0
64
0
```

So, **10.0.64.0/18**.  You can also calculate your broadcast:

```
$ dc -e '2i 00001010 p 00000000 p 01111111 p 11111111 p'
10
0
127
255
```

Or, **10.0.127.255/18**.

And the network **10.0.96.0/28** is certainly within this range.

Answer (score 0):

/18 corresponds to a netmask of 255.255.192.0, which combines with the IP address to make the network address equivalent to 10.0.64.0/18. (Every bit that isn't in the netmask, gets set to 0 to determine the first address on the network.) Every address from 10.0.64.0 to 10.0.127.255 is in that network, including 10.0.96.0/28.